# Crash Report Meaning

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, crashlytics

I just got a crash report from **Crashlytics** of my app on AppStore.. the crash report is as follows..

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3bbf1350 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3bb67fb7 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3bba436b abort + 94
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x3b14cddf abort_message + 74
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x3b14a099 default_terminate() + 24
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b6fda5b _objc_terminate() + 146
6  libc++abi.dylib                0x3b14a11b safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 78
7  libc++abi.dylib                0x3b14a1b4 std::terminate() + 19
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x3b14b62b __cxa_rethrow + 94
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b6fd9b5 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x339532a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
11 CoreFoundation                 0x339530c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode
12 GraphicsServices               0x3753133b GSEventRunModal + 74
13 UIKit                          0x3586f2b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
14 TradeMate                      0x000633d3 main (main.m:16)
```

Can anyone explain what it is?? cause its not giving anything…

Let me know if anything else is needed..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what you can see in this crash dump is that there was an uncaught exception which caused the application to terminate. You would need to look at the stacks of the other threads to get a clue. Also the rest of the crash report is important to see what actually caused the crash.

The crash reporting provided by apple usually contains a lot more details as just a stack. And the link provided by [jnix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393833/jnix) ([Demystifying iOS Application Crash Logs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs)) is for sure a good help analysing such logs.

Nevertheless, often it's necessary that you can reproduce a crash in XCode to find out the actual reason for a crash.